# Django Admin save_model() creates a new object when I only try to edit

Tags: django, django-admin

My original issue was that I was trying to attach the current user to new entries, so I override the `save_model` method under `admin.ModelAdmin` to do

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.submit_usr = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

This works great when I try to create new object or new entry in my db, but when I try to edit the existing one, it still creates a new entry

my model looks like (I took out all the settings to avoid being messy here)

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    app_name = model.CharField()
    submit_usr = models.ForeignKey()
    submit_date = model.DateTimeField()
```

I know that the `change` arg indicates if there's a change in existing entry, but I still don't have a way to tell Django that I only want to modify the current entry instead of creating a new one.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Which button you clicking in Django admin to teste it? because your code is right, but maybe you clicking to Save a new one at django instando ok clicking save the currenty object

Comment: is the code right though? Shouldn't it be `super(AppUserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)`? or is that unnecessary in modern django/python?

Comment: @DiegoVinícius I do not see an "OK" button. the "Save", "Save and add another" and "Save and continue editing" are the only buttons I see

Comment: @NicholasClaudeLeBlanc I actually tried both. Both have the same effect. I'm not sure if things work inherently different in this case. I'm using django 2.0 btw

Comment: hmmm, I'm just looking through the source. I don't have time to run my own tests right now. try printing `form.is_valid()` `change` and `obj.id` and see what you get

Comment: @NicholasClaudeLeBlanc `form.is_valid()` = `True`, `change` = `True`, `obj` doesn't have `id` attribute, from the database, it seems like there's no autoincrementing value for id. `PrimaryKey` is linked to `app_name`. Does this make editing `app_name` impossible?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you post the rest of the model?

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not change:
        obj.submit_usr = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```